# Iterate through all the classes in the project

Tags: c#, .net

I have around 50 classes in my project. Each class has some save functionality. Now i want to save the data in some required flow.

```
EG: I have classes A, B, C, D, E.

And the sequence of save might be : C, D, E, B, A
```

Now as i am having many classes, so i want to create a for loop to save the data in the flow.
To do that i was thinking to create a list of classes and then i can do something like this:

```
List<Classes> list_class = new List[] {C, D, E, B, A};
foreach (Classes item in list_class)
{
    item.Save();
}
```

**Is it possible to have this kind of functionality? If yes then how?**

**EDIT:**

```
Below you can see what i want to achieve:

List<?> Saving_Behaviour = new list[];

for (int i = 0; i < Saving_Behaviour.Length; i++)
{
   if (((Saving_Behaviour[i])Controller.GetBindingList()).HasValue())
   {
         (Saving_Behaviour[i]).Save();
    //do save
   }
}
```

Summary : In the if statement, every class checks that its instance has some values or not. Then if it has some values than it will call the save method of that class.

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: @SLaks ok...I just want to know of which type the list can be formed to create a list of classes in my project so that i can call the save function of each class by implementing a loop.

Comment: Your question is still very unclear.  You may want an interface, or reflection, or a list of delegates.

Comment: @SLaks: ok...let me edit my question and put some real stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly what interfaces are for -- you have common functionality in your objects and are *guaranteed* at compile time that that member is *implemented*.  So long as each one of your <strike>classes</strike> *objects* implement a common interface, you can easily create a container for your objects, e.g.

```
// Ensure your objects implement a common interface.
Dogs : ISaveable
Cats : ISaveable

...

// The interface (not shown) has a SaveOrder
Dogs.SaveOrder = 1;
Cats.SaveOrder = 2;

...

// Create a container that is capable of holding items implementing ISaveable 
List<ISaveable> saveItems = new List<ISaveable>();

...

// Add your items to your container
saveItems.Add(Dogs);
saveItems.Add(Cats);

...

// When it's time to save, simply enumerate through your container
foreach(var item in saveItems.OrderBy(q=>q.SaveOrder))
{
   // The interface guarantees that a Save method exists on each object
   item.Save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But i am having one more little trouble. I also want to access a common property of classes. The problem is that property is static. So i cannot use them by Implementing interfaces. Any Solution for this?